# Playwright: Saving session storage

Tags: playwright

I'm very new to Playwright. I'm trying to follow this https://playwright.dev/docs/auth#reuse-signed-in-state so I can login and then save the session for further tests.

My steps work fine in a test but once I've moved them to global-setup.ts I get a timeout:

```
import { chromium, FullConfig } from '@playwright/test'

async function globalSetup(config: FullConfig) {
  const browser = await chromium.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  

  await page.goto('MYDOMAIN/login');
  await page.locator("a[testid='googleSignIn']").click()
  await page.locator("input[type='email']").fill('MYEMAIL')
  await page.locator(
    "button[class='VfPpkd-LgbsSe VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-dgl2Hf nCP5yc AjY5Oe DuMIQc LQeN7 qIypjc TrZEUc lw1w4b']",
  ).click()
await page.locator("input[type='password']").fill('MYPASSWORD')
await page.locator(
  "button[class='VfPpkd-LgbsSe VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-dgl2Hf nCP5yc AjY5Oe DuMIQc LQeN7 qIypjc TrZEUc lw1w4b']",
).click()

  // Save signed-in state to 'storageState.json'.
  await page.context().storageState({ path: 'storageState.json' })
  await browser.close()
}

export default globalSetup
```

The above steps log me in fine in a test but now I've set my config file to use the saved session storage:

> storageState: 'storageState.json',

When I run a test I don't see a browser appear it just waits a minute and then says:

> ## locator.click: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
> =========================== logs =========================== waiting for selector "button[class='VfPpkd-LgbsSe VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ
> VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-dgl2Hf nCP5yc AjY5Oe DuMIQc LQeN7 qIypjc TrZEUc
> lw1w4b']"
>
> at ../../global-setup.ts:15
>
> 13 |   await page.locator(   14 |     "button[class='VfPpkd-LgbsSe
> VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-dgl2Hf nCP5yc AjY5Oe
> DuMIQc LQeN7 qIypjc TrZEUc lw1w4b']",
>
> > 15 |   ).click()
> > |     ^

The time out is the step just before I enter my password.
I'm running the tests with this command:

```
yarn playwright test login-page-tests --headed
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I’m facing a similar issue. I also cannot log-in via Google Auth with Chromium (it is working for me in other browsers. On Chromium I’m getting the “verify it’s you” message). Did a regular login with google worked for you, using Chromium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't count on these google login class names. Did you try running something like:

```
await page.locator('text="Next"').click()
```

Comment: Yes, that was it, for some reason when running headed vs headless the google page I was sent to was slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

Form `Playwright 1.31` you can use `dependency`. See example with `projects`:

**playwright.config.ts**:

```js
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from "@playwright/test";
import path from "path";

export const STORAGE_STATE = path.join(__dirname, 'login.json')
    
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  timeout: 10 * 1000,
  expect: {
    timeout: 3 * 1000,
  },
  testDir: './tests',
  use:{
    baseURL: 'https://google.com',
    trace: 'retain-on-failure',
    video: 'retain-on-failure',
  },
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'login',
      grep: /@login/
    },
    {
      name: 'authenticated e2e',
      grep: /@e2e/,
      dependencies: ['login'],
      use: {
        storageState: STORAGE_STATE
      }
    }

  ]
}; 

export default config;
```

**tests/example.spec.ts**:

```js
import { test} from '@playwright/test';
import { STORAGE_STATE } from '../playwright.config';
    
test('login to service @login', async({page}) => {
  await page.goto('/');
  // Do login action 
  // below example is to reject cookies from google
  await page.waitForLoadState('domcontentloaded');
  await page.keyboard.press('Tab');
  await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
  await page.getByRole('menuitem', { name: "English (United States)" }).press('Enter');
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Reject all' }).click();
  
  // Save storage:
  await page.context().storageState({path: STORAGE_STATE})
})

test('logged in test @e2e', async ({page}) => {
  await page.goto('/');
  await page.waitForLoadState('domcontentloaded');
  // BOOM - you are logged in
  // Screenshot shows that settings regarding cookies were saved
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' })
})
```

Video with example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PI50YAPTAs4&t=286s

In above example I'm using tags to identify tests: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-annotations#tag-tests